# Visual Studio VBA Excel add-in get data from stored procedure with x number of columns

Tags: visual-studio, vba, stored-procedures, add-in, multiple-columns

What I normally do to call a SQL stored procedure and display the data in excel using vba is:

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=[INSTANCE];Initial Catalog=[databasename];User ID=[user];Password=[password];")
         Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
        shXL = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
        Dim Str2 As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim j As Integer

        Str2.CommandText = "[NAME OF PROCEDURE]"
        Str2.Connection = sqlConnection1
        Str2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        reader = Str2.ExecuteReader()
        j = 2
        While reader.Read()
            shXL.Cells(5, j).Value = reader("[NAME OF COLUMN]")
            j = j +1
        End While

        sqlConnection1.Close()
```

It works, when the number of columns returned are constant.

But I have a stored procedure than returns x number of columns, so the code has to find out how many columns my stored procedure returned and display the data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Normally ;) SqlDataReader has got [FieldCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns the number of columns in the current row.

Another way is to use [Data.Datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which could be useful in your case.

```
Dim dt As Data.DataTable = new Data.DataTable()
dt.Load(reader)
Dim cc As Integer = dt.Columns.Cont 'get the count of columns
Dim rc As Integer = dt.Rows.Count 'get the count of rows
For c = 0 to cc
    For r =0 to rc
        'here extract your data ;)
    Next
Next
```